# Is there a way to compare render order of any/all Renderers in view of the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

This is for a 2D game that is HEAVY on user interfaces and menus, it's essentially a simulated operating system. So I know that sortingOrder and Layers exist, and I do use those for some things, but for more complex "is X drawn in front of Y at this point in 2d space" questions I'd LOVE to have a "global" order ID value I can get for any Renderer, and simply compare if it's greater than or less than another Renderer's value. I am not using Unity's Canvas or built-in UI systems, what we want to do is more complex than those can handle.

- Currently I'm using z-order, colliders on interactable objects, and a ray drawn "through" the objects in 3D space to determine order, but keeping z positioning in line with visual sorting order is not the easiest task in all cases, and this way I can't get data on any non-interactable visible objects.
- I found the Renderer.renderPriority variable, but that returns 0 on every object.
- Renderer.sortingOrder is the order *within* that sortingLayer, and sometimes I need to do comparisons between layers, and also sometimes we have sub-layers that would make this very difficult and require lots of recursive layer math. This comparison is going to be running OFTEN, and objects shift around in user-driven and unpredictable ways, so I can't afford to do that.

I don't see any "global" exposed value like this on Renderer itself, so I suppose my question is does the Camera perhaps store a collection of Renderer objects it can "see" that I can ping for their visual draw order? Is there any other way I can find "is X drawn in front of Y at this point in 2d space" and "sort this list of Renderers by draw order"?

Comment: I don't think there really is something built-in for knowing the draw call order for your scene up-front - at least not without "manually" recursing all SortingLayer, sortingOrder and z-depth and hierarchy depth relations between the objects as you mention

Comment: @derHugo yeah that's what I was afraid of. We can continue using our z-based system but it's definitely not my favorite option.